# Aligning 3 div Boxes within a container

Tags: html, containers

On the Page:  jerkydirect.com/base/opportunity - There are 3 boxes within the container with the picture. However the boxes do not align vertically or horizontally. How do I get all 3 boxes to show up nicely on the same line?

Here is the code:

```
<section class="plan-box opportunity">
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<h2>Choose Your Crave:</h2>

<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
<center>
<div class="package">
<h3>Twin Pack</h3>

<p>2 BAGS</p>

<ul>
    <li><span>Affiliate Price: </span><span>$19.75</span></li>
    <li><span>Retail Price:</span><span>$21.75</span></li>
    <li><span>Commission Payout:</span><span>$5.00</span></li>
</ul>
</div>
</center>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4">
                <div class="package">
                    <h3>family Pack <span></span></h3>
                    <p>4 BAGS</p>
                    <ul>
                        <li><span>Affiliate Price: </span><span>$39.50</span></li>
                        <li><span>Retail Price:</span><span>$41.50</span></li>
                        <li><span>Commission Payout:</span><span>$10</span></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4">
                <div class="package">
                    <h3>Party Pack <span></span></h3>
                    <p>10 BAGS</p>
                    <ul>
                        <li><span>Affiliate Price: </span><span>$79.75</span></li>
                        <li><span>Retail Price:</span><span>$87.75</span></li>
                        <li><span>Commission Payout:</span><span>$15</span></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div></div>
</div>
</section>


  [1]: http://jerkydirect.com/base/opportunity
```

Comment: Change your <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12"> to col-md-4 :P

Comment: That worked.  Thank you for the solution!

Comment: You're welcome, I'll put it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Change your `<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">` to `<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4">`. That way you'll have all of the divs aligned with each other equally.